# Loading a div controller based only on a specific select option

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

Hi I have a working on change function that loads a controller with div content inside a modal as shown in this photo.

[image: The Working Controller with div inside the modal]

My problem is it loads whenever I change any select options, what I want is to load the controller if only Monthly Option is selected.

**My HTML Select Option is this:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="registrationmodeofpayment" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Mode of Payment: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">

      <select class="form-control" name="registrationmodeofpayment" id="registrationmodeofpayment">
        <option value="">Select Mode of Payment</option>
        <option value="Annual">Annual (Full)</option>
        <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
      </select>

    </div>
</div>

// The div that have the id of modeofpayment.
<div class="col-md-12" id="modeofpayment"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#registrationmodeofpayment").unbind('change').bind('change', function() {
    // Loads the controller
    $("#modeofpayment").load('registration/assessModeofPayment');
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public function assessModeofPayment()  
{   

      $div3 = '</table>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <th>Monthly Tuition Fee:</th>
          <td width="210px">*Amount*</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      ';

    echo $div3;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we've got IF's for that:

```
$("#registrationmodeofpayment").unbind('change').bind('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'Monthly') {
        // Loads the controller
        $("#modeofpayment").load('registration/assessModeofPayment');
    }
});
```

Hope I've helped a little.

Comment: Thanks you so much!